# How to hide published content to anonymous user programmatically?

Tags: views, 7, users, nodes

I have created a new content type programmatically and I would like to set permission so that **anonymous users** do not see this content when it is published.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

By default, Drupals permission system does not support specific view permissions by content types. You will need a module for that. Have a look at [Controlling Access to Content Overview](https://drupal.org/node/270000). In Drupal 6 projects I have used [Taxonomy access control lite](http://drupal.org/project/tac_lite) quite offen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Drupal 7, you can look into [hook_node_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7), eg, something along these lines:

```
function YOURMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {

  // If $node is a string, the node has not yet been created and we don't care about that case.

  if (is_string($node)) {
    return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
  }

  $type =  $node->type;

  if ($op == 'view' && $type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE' && !$account->uid) {
    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }

  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;

}
```

A good place to look for more information on this would be the `node_access_example` module inside the [Examples Module](https://drupal.org/project/examples).

Comment: this is a good, lighter alternative to contrib modules

Answer (score -1):

You could use a custom module that:

- add a permission for every content type
- modify permissions to node/nid with hook_menu_alter

Obviously you can create a permission only for your custom content type.

Here is an example:

```
<?php 
/**
 * Implements hook_permission.
 */
function mymodule_permission() {
  $permissions = array();  
  foreach (node_type_get_types() as $type) {
    $permissions['view ' . $type->name . ' contents'] = array (
      'title' => t('View published contents for ' . $type->name . ' nodes'),      
      'description' => t('Let users to see nodes of type ' . $type->name),
    );
  }   
  return $permissions;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter.
 */
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['access arguments'] = array(1);
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_check_permission';
} 

/**
 * Check permission
 */
function mymodule_check_permission() {
  global $user;
  if ($node->status == 1) {
    if (user_access('view ' . $node->type . ' contents', $user) || user_access('administer nodes', $user))) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  else {
    return user_access('access content', $user);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: This approach ***totally*** overrides the `node.module`'s `access callback` routine.  A far better approach would be to implement https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7 in your module that would then be called within the existing core node access routine.

Comment: Ok, my was an example, it could be limited to some roles, and simply use the normale node_access for roles excluded from control..
However hook_node_access is better :)

Comment: precisely, that logic belongs in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7 where it would be called from the core node_access() access callback without any further alters.